# Problems with TXT record in combination with other Records

Tags: domain-name-system, lets-encrypt, txt-record

I have currently the following DNS setup.

Domain: domain.tld
Example IPv4: 1.2.3.4
Example IPv6: fe80::1

```
Host Type Destination 
* A 1.2.3.4
* AAAA fe80::1
```

This setup works perfectly as expected. If I open any software and enter notexisting.domain.tld I get a valid resolve of 1.2.3.4

Now to the problem:
If I now simply add a TXT record for a Let's Encrypt DNS Validation with the following content:

```
Host Type Destination
_acme-challenge.notexisting TXT XrcC2WczNeJNvhNfbLFjE0iawzIZTlR6BEmD4OxF-pw
```

After the TTL gets invalidated and I query the zone again I get the following result:

Only a SOA and TXT is returned for the notexisting.domain.tld.
This is weird in my opinion because if I add another subdomain to my zone the DNS will fail for the period of DNS validation. How can I prevent this from happening?

I tested with Bind and PowerDNS software and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like expected behavior considering how wildcards are supposed to work.

Wildcards only apply to branches of the tree that *do not exist*. After you add that record for `_acme-challenge.notexisting` the `notexisting` branch exists, ie, the wildcard no longer applies there.

What you want is to add the relevant records for `notexisting` rather than relying on that wildcard. (Maybe a wildcard was not the correct solution in the first place?)

If the use-case here involves adding new subdomains on the fly, both BIND and PowerDNS support dynamic updates (RFC2136), alternatively PowerDNS also has a REST API. So programmatic addition of records should be readily available for both.

Comment: So I need to add for every branch I want a new record like `notexisting A 1.2.3.4`. My problem was that I haven't found any specification that the wildcard should not fallback to the main branch. I'll accept this answer at it solves my initial problem though. Thanks

Comment: @DominikS. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034#section-4.3.3